# Can't save array in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a `has_many` relationship with another object. Because of this, Mongoid creates an attribute titled `item_ids` as an Array so I can conveniently save numerous ids as an array. However, whenever I attempt to save a new array it never actually saves. In my rails console I run the following code.

```
1.9.3p385 :035 > miss.item_ids = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 

1.9.3p385 :036 > miss.save
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
 => true 

1.9.3p385 :037 > miss.item_ids
 => []
```

As you can see when I save the object it returns true. However when I return to check out the `item_ids` I'm returned an empty array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the miss object messages

Comment: `full_messages` return an empty array.

Comment: instead of checking it in your rails console, try checking in the database console, just to make sure =)

Comment: So I should check via MongoDB?

Comment: It's just a guess but try that

Comment: It saves on MongoDB with no issues.

Comment: So I guess that item_ids is cleared after you save. I think you are checking in the wrong place.

Comment: I'm not sure where else to check then. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manually creating the relation.
Try `miss.items << item`

Now `miss.items` should return an array of items

Answer (score 3):

'item_ids' isnt an attribute, is a method that runs some queries to return only the IDs of the relationed objects and appends them on an array.

When you do something like miss.item_ids = [1,2,3] you are basically creating that field on the document, as you are using Mongo, it will store anything for you.